# Regex for a string- fuentd

Tags: regex, fluentd

> 2016-10-21 01:10:27.513|main|INFO|125.0.225.25|gdtl01db7i7h|{"instanceName":"testinstance","applicationId":"ABS3PP","transactionStatus":"C","responseCode":"0","responseDescription":"Success","initiatedTimestamp":"2016-09-19 00:00:00.0","elapsedTime":"44400.0","clientApp":"ServiceGateway~368","clientIp":"35.23.89.235","cluster":"P27C","httpMethod":"POST","requestURL":"/test/ctn"}

I need to write a regex for the above string like

```
/^(?<eventtimestamp>)\|(?<TYPE>)\|(?<LOGLEVEL>)\|(?<IPaddress>)\|(?<HOSTNAME>)\| (?<message>.*)$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you can use

```
^(?<eventtimestamp>[\d:. -]+)\|(?<TYPE>[a-zA-Z]+)\|(?<LOGLEVEL>[a-zA-Z]+)\|(?<IPaddress>[\d.]+)\|(?<HOSTNAME>[^|]+)\|(?<message>.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9go5f0/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string/line
- `(?<eventtimestamp>[\d:. -]+)` - 1+ digits, `:`, `.`, spaces, `-`
- `\|` - a literal `|`
- `(?<TYPE>[a-zA-Z]+)\|` - 1+ letters and a `|`
- `(?<LOGLEVEL>[a-zA-Z]+)\|` - 1+ letters and a `|`
- `(?<IPaddress>[\d.]+)\|` - 1+ digits or `.` and a `|`
- `(?<HOSTNAME>[^|]+)\|` - 1+ chars other than `|` and a `|`
- `(?<message>.*)` - any 0+ chars up to the...
- `$` - end of string/line.